# enumerate error

Tags: errors, enumerate

I'm using several types of {enumerate} in my article. It's run normally if I use a new document.

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{enumerate}  
\begin{document}  

\begin{enumerate}  
    \item fisrt  
    \item second  
    \item third  
\end{enumerate}  
Another list  
\begin{enumerate}[{A.5.}1.]  
\item  
\item  
\item  
\item  
\end{enumerate}  
\end{document}
```

But, when I try to use it in my main document, there some erroneous message.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twocolumn,twoside, a4paper]{article}  
\usepackage{microtype} % Slightly tweak font spacing for aesthetics  
\usepackage[bahasa]{babel} % Language hyphenation and typographical rules  
\usepackage[left=2.50cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.50cm, bottom=2.50cm]{geometry}   
\usepackage[hang,small,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=it,up]{caption}    
\usepackage{booktabs}    
\usepackage{enumitem}    
\usepackage{titling}     
\usepackage{hyperref}    
\usepackage{titlesec}    
\usepackage{abstract}    
\usepackage{fancyhdr}    
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{hyphenat}  
\usepackage{amssymb}  
\usepackage{enumerate}  
\addto\captionsbahasa{\renewcommand{\abstractname}{ABSTRAK}}   
\addto\captionsbahasa{\renewcommand{\refname}{REFERENSI}}  
\renewcommand{\abstractnamefont}{\normalfont\bfseries}   
\renewcommand{\abstracttextfont}{\normalfont\itshape}    
\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}}    
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\textbf{\Alph{subsection}}}   

\titleformat{\section}[block]{\large\bfseries\centering}{\thesection.}{0.3em}{}   
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\bfseries\normalsize}{\thesubsection.}{0.3em}{}   \titleformat{\subsubsection}[block]{\bfseries\normalsize}{\thesubsubsection}{0.3em}{}  
\setlist[itemize]{noitemsep}    
\setlist[enumerate]{noitemsep}    

\fancyhead{}   
\pagestyle{fancy}    
\fancyhead[LO]{Journal Issue}  
\fancyhead[RE]{Author - \textit{Title\ldots}}  
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}  

\setlength{\droptitle}{-4\baselineskip}    
\pretitle{\begin{center}\LARGE\bfseries}    
    \posttitle{\end{center}}    
\title{Article title}  
} % Article title  
\author{%  
    \normalfont{\textbf{Author1}}$^{1)}$,  
    \normalfont{\textbf{Author2}}$^{2)}$\\[1ex]  
    \normalsize$^{1,2)}${Institution Units}\\  
    \normalsize{Institution Org}\\  
    \normalsize{Address}\\[1ex]  
    \normalsize $^{1)}$  
    \href{mailto:emailadress1@email.com}{emailadress1@email.com}\\  
    \normalsize $^{2)}$  
    \href{mailto:emailadress2@email.com}{emailadress1@email.com}}  
\cfoot{\thepage}  
\setcounter{page}{18}  
\date{}   
\renewcommand{\maketitlehookd}{%  
    \begin{abstract}  
        \noindent   
        Abstract is here  

        \noindent  
        \textbf{Kata kunci}: keyword1, keyword2, keyword3   
    \end{abstract}  
}  
\begin{document}  
    \maketitle  
\section{Pendahuluan}  
\subsection{Rumusan Masalah}  
\begin{enumerate}  
    \item item1  
    \item item2  
\end{enumerate}  
\section{Metode}  
\begin{enumerate}[{A.5.}1.]  
    \item fisrt  
    \item second  
    \item third  
\end{enumerate}  

\end{document}
```

Please help, I don't have any idea how the errors can exist. 
Thank you.

Comment: When editing your post, there is a button `{}` which allows you to turn the selection into something that is recognizable as code. (Just in case you're wondering what happened to your post.)

Comment: If you (1) remove the unmatched `}` before `% Article title`, (2) remove `\usepackage{enumitem}` and (3) `\setlist[itemize]{noitemsep}    
\setlist[enumerate]{noitemsep}`, it compiles for me without problems. Is it intentional to use `enumerate` **and** `enumitem` together?

Comment: You shouldn't use [`enumerate`](//ctan.org/pkg/enumerate) and [`enumitem`](//ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) together. One *or* the other.

Comment: Unrelated: You're loading `hyperref` too early. Place it at the end of the `\usepackage`... - series